# How to sign into "root" account by default on Windows Subsystem for Linux Bash terminal

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1607

Windows 10's Anniversary Update just came out and I immediately installed the Windows Subsystem for Linux to see how it fares. I found only one major shortcoming so far: there was no obvious way to use the root account as the default.

I know it goes against a lot of best practices and what not, but I personally don't like having to remember to type `sudo` in front of most commands. This can get especially annoying when I open a text file for editing with `nano` only to discover I have to abandon my changes because I didn't use `sudo`.

Is there any way to make the terminal start as root by default?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The command to set the default Linux user is different in different versions of Windows.

**For versions of WSL up to the Fall Creators Update**, run the following command in an elevated Windows command prompt:

```
lxrun /setdefaultuser root
```

For installations **after** the Fall Creators Update, the command is:

```
<distro> config --default-user root
```

Substitute the distro's exe name for `<distro>` in the command above.  So, if you're running Ubuntu, the command would be:

```
ubuntu config --default-user root
```

For openSUSE...

```
opensuse-42 config --default-user root
```

And, for SUSE Linux Enterprise Server, the command is...

```
sles-12 config --default-user root
```

**Again, all of these commands are performed from an elevated Windows command prompt.**

Note:
The examples above are for the `root` user.  You may specify any other existing username in place of `root`.

Comment: For the newer Ubuntu 18.04 distro, the command is:

ubuntu1804 config --default-user root

Comment: Where can I see if I use the WSL fall creater update?

Comment: lxrun does not work in my powershell. I use Wsl Debian, do you know the command for this to start the app as root?

Comment: `ubuntu2004 config --default-user root` for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 18):

In a command prompt with elevated permissions run the command `lxrun /setdefaultuser root`

**lxrun** is the tool for performing administrative operations on the LX subsystem.

Comment: Just to clarify: the lxrun command should be executed in a *Windows* command prompt. This solution works great.

Comment: The `lxrun.exe` command is no longer supported.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
ubuntu1604 config --default-user root & ubuntu1604.exe
```

I tried the solutions mentioned above but somehow I always end up with the user login rather than root

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me with these modifications: `ubuntu config --default-user root & ubuntu.exe`

Comment: This worked for me, but being on Ubuntu 18.04 I needed to use `ubuntu1804 config --default-user <username>

Answer (score 3):

Try my way if someone still needed.

My computer

- Windows 10 winver: 21H1(19043).
- Subsystem: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Open Registry Editor with shortcut key: windows + r.

type: regedit and enter.

Go to this path:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss

and find the "DistributionName" you are using. (Ubuntu-18.04 is mine)
Modify this name "DefaultUid" set value equal 0 then click Ok button to save.
then log off and log in to reset Registry.

Open your bash shell and enjoy it.

0 is the root user's id, you can check by running this command
`cat /etc/passwd;`
and find root user.

Comment: worked for me :)

Comment: Works like a charm! But I didn't even need to do this: "then log off and log in to reset Registry."