# How I make root the default account on my W10 Anniversary Linux Subsystem, and how do I change it back to non-root?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Last week, after going thru the internet, I was able to find how to make this appear when opening up Bash Ubuntu on Windows 10 Anniversary:

```
root@myComputerName:~#
```

I want to be able to switch back and forth between that and the default user shell. I can temporarily get back to normal with

```
su - ubuntuUserName
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  We don't know what you did, to make the default user root, care to provide us with that information

Comment: I don't remember. Either this https://superuser.com/questions/1107986/how-to-sign-into-root-account-by-default-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-bash-t or this https://www.howtogeek.com/261417/how-to-change-your-user-account-in-windows-10s-ubuntu-bash-shell/

Comment: Alright, so set the default user back, using one of those approaches and update your question to reflect which one.  I can't submit an answer if I don't know what you did.

Comment: Use less "etc/passwd" and provide the output

Comment: please help me. I barely know what I'm doing and I'm scared. I don't know how to set the default user back. I just sought root so I could do the necessary things to compile Swift on my Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Worst case you just reset your WSL install, I won't do anything, until your question is clear.  I want to help, but to help, I must understand what you did and what you want.  Comments won't get me to that point